# Data into rows and colums

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm relatively new to this, I've written a function in Google Apps Script, getting data from an API.

The problem is that it's inserted into one single cell, instead of multiple rows and columns.

Can anybody help?

Tried googling examples

What I do

```
function spotpriser() { 
  var priser = 'api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices' + '?start=2022-07-01&end=2022-07-02' + '&sort=HourDK'; 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(priser); 
  Logger.log(response); 
  var fact = response.getContentText(); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([fact]); 
}
```

Comment: please provide code and better describe what's happening right now and what you would like to do

Comment: function spotpriser() {
var priser = 'https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices'
+ '?start=2022-07-01&end=2022-07-02'
+ '&sort=HourDK';

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(priser);
Logger.log(response);

var fact = response.getContentText();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([fact]);
}

Comment: I need to g’et the data into columns and rows. This script only inserts the data into 1 cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do `getRange(1,1).setValue()` it is normal that all the data get inserted into one cell only: the one define by the range (aka A1).

Instead what you probably want to do is to get a larger range, corresponding the dimensions of your retrieved data.

For example, let's say you retrieved 3 lines of data, and one line of data is supposed to be displayed on 2 columns.

You first need to create an array of size 5 (nb of rows) where each element will also be an array, of size 2 (nb of cols for each element).

```
let myArray = [
  [elt1_col1_value, elt1_col2_value],
  [elt2_col1_value, elt2_col2_value],
  [elt3_col1_value, elt3_col2_value]
]
```

Then you can insert this array into the right number of cells, i.e defining the right range

```
sheet.getRange(1,1,myArray.length,myArray[0].length).setValues(myArray); // start at row 1, col 1, insert the right number of rows and cols based on the array
```

Note that I use setValue**s** (with the s) to indicate that it writes in several cells.

Also make sure there is at least one element in `myArray` otherwise `myArray[0].length` will throw an error.

[Documentation for getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I cant get the script to merge the data into the array.
Also, the number of rows is not definer, and Can change

Comment: Show us what `fact` looks like and we might help

Comment: As of this point, om Down to this:
[HourUTC, HourDK, Pricearea, SpotpriceDKK, SpotpriceEUR], [2022-06-30T22:00:00,2022-07-01T00:00:00,DK1,1998.869995,268.709991],[2022-06-30T22:00:00,2022-07-01T00:00:00,DK2,1998.869995,268.709991],[2022-06-30T22:00:00,2022-07-01T00:00:00,NO2,1887.880005,253.789993],[2022-06-30T22:00:00,2022-07-01T00:00:00,SE3,1001.260010,134.600006]….

It contintues

Comment: it's weird, when I go to https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices I got the results in JSON, much better to manipulate then. Are you sure of what you're copypasting ?

Comment: That because ive tried to alter it to fit an array, as you descriped.
But if its easier with the raw data

Comment: so you're on the right track. You simply need to call sheet.getRange().setValues. I have updated my code so it's based on the array dimensions

Comment: var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(1,1,myArray.length,myArray.length[0]).setValues(myArray);
}

Get error:
Exception: The parameters (number,number,number,null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.

Comment: The fuld code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rr5fj5byb0cyi1e/code.txt?dl=0

Comment: it's `myArray[0].length`, not `myArray.length[0]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
I got a new error:
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.

Comment: @KimHinge This is a Question Answer site. One question. One answer for that question. This is not a forum or a help site. If you have follow up questions or errors,  search for that error and if you're unable to fix it and you think  the community can benefit from a new question, ask a new question!

Comment: Ok, thanks. Im new here. But why is it that Way?